# avoid disordered dataframe by read json

Tags: pandas

I read a JSON file into dataframe
And I expect the dataframe's index should be increasing by **numeric**

That is `0,1,2,3,...,9,10,11,...,99,100,101,...`

But the result is not my expect.

I generated the JSON by `df.to_json()`

How could I fix the problem thanks.

[image]

[JSON data sample](https://gist.githubusercontent.com/poc7667/fd74143ef3f5aca48c4f/raw/data.json)

Comment: `df.reset_index().drop('index', axis=1)`. The real question is though, why the index gets mixed up in the first place...

Comment: It looks like it's confused the id with the index, is the df loaded correctly otherwise or do you want to just `reindex` or `reset_index()` the df?

Answer (score 0):

Wild guess: You called `to_json` on a pre-filtered `DataFrame` where some rows were omitted in the process of data cleansing. `to_json` preserves the `id` and reading it back in using `pd.read_json` restores the index using the values sotre in the `id` fields.

A possible solution is to call `df.reset_index(drop=True)` to reindex your new `DataFrame` with ordered numbers according to your needs.

Hope that helps.